Show $M^2$ is of class D if $M$ is a martingale bounded in $L^2$
Let $M$ be a martingale null at $0$ and bounded in $L^2$. Then $M^2$ is a submartingale (just apply Jensen's inequality), and by Doob's $L^2$ inequality, we have
$$E\left[\sup_t M_t^2\right]\leq 4E\left[M_{\infty}^2\right]<\infty$$
Then, how can we show $M^2$ is of class D, in that $\{M^2_T: T \text{ is a finite stopping time}\}$ is uniform integrable?
Background: I encountered this problem when I am learning the definition of the angle-bracket process $\langle M \rangle$  from the Doob-Meyer decomposition of $M^2$ (pg. 376, vol. 2 of the book Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales by Rogers and William).

After some searching, I figured out the solution to my problem. I post it below in case someone needs it in the future.
Lemma 1. Suppose that $Y$ is a nonnegative random variable with $\mathrm{E}(Y)<\infty$, and that $|X_i|\leq Y$ for each $i\in I$. Then the family of random variables $\mathcal{X}=\{X_i: i\in I\}$ is uniformly integrable.
For Proof, see point 6 of this note.
Now, it is clear that the family $\{M^2_T: T \text{ is a finite stopping time}\}$ is dominated by the random variable
$$Y(\omega):= \sup_t M^2_t(\omega)$$
and that $Y$ is integrable according to Doob's L2 inequality. It follows that the family $\{M^2_T: T \text{ is a finite stopping time}\}$ is uniformly integrable and $M^2$ is of class D.
